# How to scale a canvas during an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, html5-canvas

I have two buttons that allow zoom in and zoom out of my canvas animation

```
<button id="zoomInButton">Zoom ++</button>
<button id="zoomOutButton">Zoom -- </button>

 <canvas id="myCanvasmatchPage" > 
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support canvas technology
</canvas>
```

And I have an animation loop (omitted) using setInterval and canvas. In order to not have the scaling happen each setInterval it has to be out of the draw function loop. In fact the ctx.scale is reset on button click.

```
$('#myCanvasmatchPage').attr({width:100,height:200}).css({width:'100px',height:'200px'});       

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvasmatchPage");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(0.5,0.5);

var nextFrame =0;
var animationData = [];

var canvasZoom = 1; //initial is scale 100%
var incrementZoom = 0.05;
$("#zoomInButton").click(function ()
   {
     canvasZoom += incrementZoom;
     ctx.scale(canvasZoom, canvasZoom);
   });
 $("#zoomOutButton").click(function ()
   {
     if (canvasZoom > 1){//i dont want to allow a less than 100% scale zoom
           canvasZoom -= incrementZoom; 
           ctx.scale(canvasZoom, canvasZoom);
    }
   });  


var draw = function(){
    //cannot set scale within animation loop! keeps resetting!
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(images['background'], 0, 0, 622, 924, 0, 0, 311, 462);

                if (nextFrame<=animationData.length){
                    //animation loop
                }else{
                    clearTimeout(draw);//get out of the loop
                    return;
                }

                nextFrame++;    
    }
    setInterval(draw,200);
```

My current experience with this code is that zoomIn 'works' but zoomOut doesn-t. Console logging has shown me that the canvasZoom does go up and down by 0.05 consistently (also 0.05000001 ha ha sometimes) but the canvas will not zoom negatively.

It makes me think that the problem is in the clearing of the canvas and not the scaling.

Comment: do you intent to do something else than zooming (rotation/translation/skew) ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist, actually yeah, rotation and also a way to move the animation's 'centre spot'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the quite common mistake to think that scale will *set* the scale, when the Canvas's context2D is a state machine, which will cumulate each change on top of each other (expl scale X2 then scale x2 == scale X4 ).

The common answer to this issue is to save() your context, do your transforms, do your drawings, then to restore() it.

So just to give you direction (untested) :

```
function Transform() {
   this.scale = 1;
   this.rotation = 0;
   this.translation = {x:0, y:0 };
   this.zoomIn = function () {
    this.scale+=0.5;
   };
   this.zoomOut = function () {
    this.scale-=0.5;
   };
   this.translate(x,y) = function (x,y)  { 
     this.translation.x+=x;  // OR +=x*currentZoom;
     this.translation.y+=y;  // OR +=y*currentZoom;
   };
   this.rotate = function (angle) {
      this.rotation+=angle;
   };
   this.applyTransform = function (ctx) {
       ctx.translate(translation.x, translation.y);  // ?? order ??
       ctx.scale(currentZoom, currentZoom);          // ?? order ??
       ctx.rotate(rotation);                   
   }
}

var imageTransform = new Transform();

function drawImage(img) { 
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(img.width/2, img.height/2);
  imageTransform.applyTransform(ctx);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -img.wdth/2, -img.height/2);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

The order in which you translate/scale/rotate depends in fact of your intent : are you moving the camera, or moving the image ? Are you scaling the camera or the image ? (question relevant only if there's more than one item to show).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to do the changes for the scale in a minute. Regarding the prioritising of other transforms (very clever you foreseeing the possibility), well the scenario is that you are watching an animation of a football match (so more than one object to transform). The viewer WILL be able to zoom in/out  and either keep the ball centre stage or go far from the ball to inspect a different part of the pitch. The rotate will allow viewing portrait or landscape.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at your answer now, your initial comment was enough to solve this problem in a primitive way. (see my answer below) Thanks again. Looking into your solution now.

Comment: I'm concerned, as I said in my question, that having the transforms inside the draw function of an animation is undesirable. Maybe the more primitive method with referring to the context only via click function is better. What do you think?

Comment: My top priority to *simplify* things when i deal with canvas is to always 'keep it clean', meaning doing only save/transform/draw/restore operations. Still there are special cases when i don't : most easy example is if i use a temporary canvas for a special purpose, then i let its context in whatever state that goes. Two examples for your case : 1) you might want to draw the score always at same place/size 2) you might want to draw a minimap of the game to show overall action even when zoomed in. For those cases i would either go for multiple layered canvases... or keep context always clean.

Comment: Update : 1) so to answer clearly : no. do not store data inside an object that is not under your control (you can set a transform with  setTransform, but you can't read it). 2) i updated my answer in OOP. ! warning, untested code !

Comment: Thanks again, much appreciated. I think you are right about making it more robust with OOP. (rather than incrementally solve each feature). On the case, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome ! OOP will also allow for easy reuse in case you want a minimap or any other feature. Accept the answer if i just scored a GOOOOAAAAAAAL :-)

Comment: Goal to GameAlchemist! Top left corner no chance for the keeper, especially when he realised that he wanted the canvas dimensions to change too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I look into @GameAlchemist 's more thorough solution, here would be a solution for a simple transformation problem. Thanks to GameAlchemist for pointing out (very importantly!) that scale changes are cumulative!

In the click function, it's important to keep a clean copy of the base to scale against (here initialZoom)

```
    var initialZoom = 1;    //100% same as container (less border)
    var zoomCounter = 1;
    var incrementZoom = 0.05;
    var canvasZoom = 1;//just to declare

 $("#zoomInButton").click(function ()
   {
     canvasZoom = initialZoom + incrementZoom;
    zoomCounter = zoomCounter + incrementZoom;//so i can track compared to original and block cumulative < 100&
     ctx.scale(canvasZoom, canvasZoom);
   });
 $("#zoomOutButton").click(function ()
   {
     if (zoomCounter > 1){//i dont want to allow a less than 100% scale zoom
           canvasZoom = initialZoom - incrementZoom;
           zoomCounter = zoomCounter - incrementZoom;
           ctx.scale(canvasZoom, canvasZoom);
    }
   });
```

Now off to see if GameAlchemist-s solution allows me easier multi transforms!

Comment: While this should be working with scaling only, i fear headaches when you add rotation/translation. In fact i consider only two viables options : First is like my answer, but with OOP, so all properties are within one single object, which not only is cleaner, but also allows for tweening or other features. Second is quite the same, but you'd build a transform matrix by yourself to update the transform with a single setTransform. It would be faster, but i fear it is over-optimisating, first solution should be fast enough.